# UWP Binding to Visibility property of a FontIcon

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to bind the `Visibility` property of a `FontIcon` to an enum property in my view model using a converter, but for some reason it throws an exception

> Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.FontIcon' to type 
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding'

What I want to achieve is that depending on the current value of `CurrentSortOrder` hide or show an icon inside the `MenuFlyoutItem`

View model code:

```
public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private TaskSortType _currentTaskSortOrder = TaskSortType.BY_NAME_ASC;
    public TaskSortType CurrentSortOrder
    {
        get => _currentTaskSortOrder;
        set => Set(ref _currentTaskSortOrder, value);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Page
x:Class="UWPTests.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:converters="using:UWPTests.Converters"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="using:UWPTests"
xmlns:localModels="using:UWPTests.Models"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
DataContext="{x:Bind ViewModel}"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <converters:TaskSortTypeToVisibilityConverter x:Key="TaskSortTypeToVisibilityConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Sort" Label="Sort">
        <AppBarButton.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="By name">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Asc">
                        <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
                            <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE73E;" Visibility="{Binding CurrentSortOrder, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource TaskSortTypeToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Bind localModels:TaskSortType.BY_NAME_ASC}}" />
                        </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Desc">
                        <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
                            <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE73E;" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>
                </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </AppBarButton.Flyout>
    </AppBarButton>
</Grid>
```

Converter:

```
public class TaskSortTypeToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Visibility OnTrue { get; set; }
    public Visibility OnFalse { get; set; }

    public TaskSortTypeToVisibilityConverter()
    {
        OnFalse = Visibility.Collapsed;
        OnTrue = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is null || parameter is null)
            return Visibility.Collapsed;

        var currentOrder = (TaskSortType)value;
        var targetOrder = (TaskSortType)parameter;

        return currentOrder == targetOrder ? OnTrue : OnFalse;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is Visibility == false)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        if ((Visibility)value == OnTrue)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Edit:

I get the exception here: `this.InitializeComponent();`

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public TestViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        ViewModel = new TestViewModel();
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

```
public enum TaskSortType
{
    BY_NAME_ASC = 0,
    BY_NAME_DESC = 1,
    BY_UPDATED_DATE_ASC = 2,
    BY_UPDATED_DATE_DESC = 3,
}
```

Comment: please mention where and on which line you get the exception

Comment: @touseefbsb See my edit

Comment: in the convert method you should be returning a visibility instead you are returning a boolean and in convert back you should be returning a "TaskSortType" instead you are again returning a boolean

Comment: also please show the enum "TaskSortType" code I want to see what values it has,

Comment: I need to see the enum code "TaskSortType" then I will probably have a solution for you.

Comment: @touseefbsb Added the enum

Comment: ok, now please elaborate which 2 values do you want the visibility to be collapsed and which 2 for visible? because there are 4 enum values here, and visibility has 2 states, either it can be visible or collapsed.

Comment: @touseefbsb for that i use the `ConverterParameter={x:Bind localModels:TaskSortType.BY_NAME_ASC}}`. If the `CurrentSortOrder` in my viewmodel does not match the one i pass in the `ConverterParameter` then i want the icon to be hidden otherwise i want it to be visible

Comment: so basically if the value is "by_name_asc" icon should be visible, otherwise collapsed?

Comment: @touseefbsb yes exactly. I fixed my ConvertBack method but still its throwing the exception.

Comment: your data binding is OneWay you do not need a ConvertBack method at all you can leave it empty

Comment: also try 'ConverterParameter=localModels:TaskSortType.BY_NAME_ASC'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that i cant use x:Bind directly in the `ConverterParameter` .. So i ended with the following:

I added in my page resources:

```
<localModels:TaskSortType x:Key="TaskSortByNameAsc">BY_NAME_ASC</localModels:TaskSortType>
<localModels:TaskSortType x:Key="TaskSortByNameDesc">BY_NAME_DESC</localModels:TaskSortType>
<localModels:TaskSortType x:Key="TaskSortByUpdatedDateAsc">BY_UPDATED_DATE_ASC</localModels:TaskSortType>
<localModels:TaskSortType x:Key="TaskSortByUpdatedDateDesc">BY_UPDATED_DATE_DESC</localModels:TaskSortType>
```

And then i replaced the `ConverterParameter` binding with the following:

```
 <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE73E;" Visibility="{Binding CurrentSortOrder, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource TaskSortTypeToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource BY_NAME_ASC}}" />
```

Another workaround would be to pass the corresponding value in the `ConverterParameter`, for example `ConverterParameter=0` or `ConverterParameter="BY_NAME_ASC"`and the cast that parameter to the corresponding enum value

Comment: Another method would be to x:Bind to a function, for example `Visibility={x:Bind VisByName(CurrentSortOrder), Mode=OneWay}`, where `VisByName` is a method on MainPage that takes in CurrentSortOrder and returns a Visibility. Is it a better option? Eh. It's just an option.